# Logging INFO to Django Server's STDOUT

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up logging on a Django server. I want to be able to log arbitrary INFO-level strings to the server's standard out, so it appears alongside the standard Django messages that look like this:

```
[24/Feb/2014 20:37:03] "POST /v1/events/ HTTP/1.1" 201 0
```

Here is my current logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        #'file': {
            #'level': 'DEBUG',
            #'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            #'filename': '/tmp/djdebug.log',
        #},
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propogate': True,
            'level': 'INFO'
        }
        #'django': {
            #'handlers': ['file'],
            #'propagate': True,
            #'level': 'DEBUG',
        #},
    }
}
```

In a models.py file in an app for my django project, I do the following at the top:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then, within some code, I write run the following:

```
logger.info('triggering notifications')
```

The code hits the point where this is called, but nothing is written to the server's stdout. Am I missing something? I'm running this locally, and DEBUG = True, but I'd like the INFO messages to be displayed even in production with DEBUG = False.

Answer (score 4):

`__name__` is the name of the python module that contains the logger. So, to make your logger work, you should rename your logger in settings.py from `django` to *name of the module from where you calling* `getLogger`. Second option - just change `__name__` to `django`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

**late update to your comment:**

> Yeah, but I still want all of my loggers namespaced. I'm just
>   wondering if there's a way to set a "base line" configuration for all
>   modules and have everything automatically inherit from that. Using
>   'django' for everything is out of the question, totally unmodular.

You just need to add ***'your_project_name'*** logger to loggers list. The dotted paths of logger names define a hierarchy. For example, if you need, let's say, file log for ***'some_application'*** in your project and all other applications log messages (`INFO` level) should going to console only, then your loggers list can look like this:

```
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'INFO'
    },

    #...

    'your_project_name': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'your_project_name.some_application': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'propagate': True, # propagate here to root project level
                           # logger to also print this message to console
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },

    #...

    'your_project_name.some_application.models': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'], #, 'console']
        'propagate': True, # if file and console needed,
                           # but 'console' can be added to handlers
                           # and propagate set to False
                           # to avoid this log messages in file...
        'level': 'ERROR',
    },

}
```

Calling `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in ***some_application*** will get you logger, that should log all messages to file and also propagate to root project logger to display them on console. All other applications modules `__name__` will match only your root project logger: `your_project_name` that will print messages on console only. If needed you can, add one more level to tree, for example ***your_project_name.some_application.models*** that can use `mail_admins` handler to report some db problems to admins. You can change logger levels on different loggers in hierarchy of course!

Comment: Surely there's a way to set reasonable defaults for ALL modules in a given project though? I have multiple apps in the project, and I don't want to be pasting the same massive list of JSON for every one of them.

Comment: @user1427661 what do you mean by 'set reasonable defaults for ALL modules'?

Comment: i.e., what I have set for 'django' in the original message's code. I want its handler to be console, I want propogate set to True, and I want level set to 'INFO'. I'd like that to be the default level for every module that uses logging, so I don't have to type every module into my settings file or update it every time I add a new module.

Comment: @user1427661 as i said - use 'django' when you getting logger in module: `logger = logging.getLogger('django')`, no other changes needed. If you want to use `__name__` as name of logger, you should make logger name in settings.py equal module name from where you calling `getLogger`...

Comment: Yeah, but I still want all of my loggers namespaced. I'm just wondering if there's a way to set a "base line" configuration for all modules and have everything automatically inherit from that. Using 'django' for everything is out of the question, totally unmodular.